# Fedora - Tor proxy refusing connection?

Tags: firefox, proxy, fedora, tor, rhel7

[ FEDORA 19 ]

I am trying to configure mozilla firefox to use tor network.

I downloaded tor client, it seems to run and be active on port 9050. But proxy server in firefox rejects connection.

Any ideas ? :C I am new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is screenshot of my screen and terminal output:

[screen CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f5IS.png)